# PHP - Find strings in text file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code index.php :

```
$d00m = file_get_contents('named.txt');
foreach ($d00m as $dom) {
    preg_match_all('#zone "(.*)"#', $dom, $domsws);
    $site = $domsws[0];
}
echo "$site";
```

The `named.txt` file content content is:

```
zone "site.com" {
zone "site2.com" {
zone "site3.com" {
```

I need a sorted output in browser :

```
site1.com
site2.com
site3.com
```

Comment: Do: `print_r($domsws);` and you will see what you are looking for. (Also you may want to `explode()` your file string into an array first)

Comment: can you give an exemple !!

Comment: `explode()` your file string by a new line and then put the `print_r($domsws);` into the foreach loop

Comment: `$domsws` is a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is for each capture group, the second dimension is for each match.

Answer (score 0):

`$domsws` is a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is for the whole regexp match and each capture group, the second dimension is for each match (you can invert this by using the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag). Since the site names are in capture group 1, they're in `$domsws[1]`, which is an array of all these capture group matches. So you should do:

Also, `$d00m` is a string, not an array, so you don't need to loop over it.

```
$d00m = file_get_contents('named.txt');
preg_match_all('#zone "(.*)"#', $d00m, $domsws);
$site = $domsws[1];
print_r($site);
```

Comment: *The first dimension is for each capture group, the second dimension is for each match* - it is vice versa. First come matches, then captures.

Comment: @stribizhev The first element is matches, the second element is capture group 1, then capture group 2. Those are all in the first dimension.

Comment: No, look [here](http://ideone.com/kuxf6x): `[0] => Array` contains full matched values and `[1] => Array` contains captured texts. With PREG_SET_ORDER, it [is different](http://ideone.com/GdN2XH).

Comment: You're confusing elements with dimensions. The first dimension is everything with just one square bracket `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. The second dimension has two square brackets: `[0][0]`, `[0][1]`, `[1][0]`, etc.

Comment: Ok, perhaps. That sounds misleading :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `file` instead of `file_get_contents`.  This will give you an array with each line being an item of the array.  No messing with `explode`.

```
$d00m = file('named.txt');
```

Then loop through them and do a preg_replace to store the value into a new array.  You can then sort that array using `sort` or `natsort`.  I personally would use the latter.

Here's some code you can play around with:

```
<?php


// CREATE A NEW ARRAY TO HOLD OUR OUTPUT
$site_list = array();


// IMPORT THE FILE INTO AN ARRAY
$d00m = file('named.txt');


// LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY AND STORE THE SITE NAME INTO THE ARRAY
foreach ($d00m as $dom) {

    $site_list[] = preg_replace('~zone "(.*?)" \{~', '$1', $dom);

}


// DO A NATURAL SORT OF THE NUMBERS
natsort($site_list);


// DUMP OUT THE DATA
print_r($site_list);
```

Using `preg_replace` provides a way to keep the part you want `$1` and throw away everything else.  `$1` contains whatever was captured inside the parenthesis.  `(.*?)` means to grab any character `.`, any number of times `*` until you hit the next part of the expression `?`.  In this case, it will stop once it gets to the closing quotation mark.

Here's an example for you.

With a `named.txt` file like this:

```
zone "site.com" {
zone "site2.com" {
zone "site3.com" {
zone "site16.com" {
zone "site4.com" {
zone "site77.com" {
zone "site34.com" {
zone "site5.com" {
zone "site999.com" {
zone "site34.com" {
zone "site11.com" {
zone "site8.com" {
zone "site64.com" {
```

You'd get a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => site.com

    [1] => site2.com

    [2] => site3.com

    [4] => site4.com

    [7] => site5.com

    [11] => site8.com

    [10] => site11.com

    [3] => site16.com

    [9] => site34.com

    [6] => site34.com

    [12] => site64.com

    [5] => site77.com

    [8] => site999.com

)
```